# Does anyone know what parameters to pass to dwmapi.dll ordinal #113? 

Tags: winapi, windows-7

Does anyone know what parameters to pass to dwmapi.dll ordinal #113? (Windows 7)

I'm trying to incorporate this method into an application that I'm writing. From what I can tell, this method is responsible for doing the Aero peek thing for windows. If I pass no params to the method it will show the desktop and outlines of all open, non-maximized windows. Nothing happens when I try passing parameters - which I've done using trial and error.. mostly error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you take a look at Raymond Chen's blog in five to ten years where he rants about some obsolete dwmapi.dll function Microsoft still supports because there are apps depending on it even though it is undocumented, you'll know you shouldn't have done it today :)

Answer (score 11):

Don't do it. It's undocumented for a reason and is subject to change and/or removal at any time. Given that Windows 7 hasn't been release yet you won't even be able to guarantee that it'll be there in the final version.

Comment: I'm sure that it's undocumented for a reason. But, I'm creating this program for myself and have no plans to release it. I really don't think that this method is going to change or be removed.. and if it is then I'll find an alternative to using it.

Answer (score 1):

Your tags are inconsistent. An API is an application programming interface. Ordinal #113 is undocumented because it's not part of the interfaces for applications. It is likely present because the OS needs it itself, or because the current RC hasn't finished removing it, etc.

Comment: I highly doubt that the method will be changed/removed in a future version of Windows 7. It hasn't changed since the first release/leaked builds.

Comment: @softwerx: LOL... let me introduce you to Bob. He worked on a team called WinFS.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've used to mimic Alt-Tab with AeroPeek feature.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...   
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint = "#113", SetLastError = true)]
            internal static extern uint DwmpActivateLivePreview(uint a, IntPtr b, uint c, uint d);
...
//To call it
IntPtr peekHwnd = //<-- here goes the application Handle to aeropeek
//to enable
DwmpActivateLivePreview(1, peekHwnd, 0, 1);
...
//to disable
DwmpActivateLivePreview(0, peekHwnd, 0, 1);
```

Use it carefully, since many comments tell you that it is undocumented for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think is because aeropeek is not supported by all windows editions, home basic is not supported, maybe you can implement your own window peek or at least fake it using alpha transparency (while drawing some border) and querying for underlying windows using the window rectangle coordinates like the rectangle collision detection algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Please go read [Raymond Chen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/) until you realize this is a really, really, really bad idea!

Comment: I've read this blog before. I understand the consequences..
I just want to know what kind of parameters to pass the method as of now. If it changes I'll at least have an idea of how to update my own code to reflect its changes.

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason that apps can't activate Aero Peek - the user gets to choose when that happens, not you.

Comment: The program I'm building is a taskbar application that mimics the Windows 7 taskbar. I'd like to try to reproduce it as closely as possible - this is the reason for wanting to use Aero Peek.